# New to using Jackson API

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to set up using Jackson as my JSON parser.

I downloaded the 3 `jackson-core, jackson-annotation, jackson-databind` jars and added them to my project external jars. All are the latest 2.6.3 version

When I try to do a `ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();` it says error `ObjectMapper cannot be resolved to a type`

Not sure if I am importing the correct libraries. I assume by doing `import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;` I am importing all?

Comment: Can you please review my answer and tell me, if it helped you, or not? If it helped, then you can think about [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer and/or upvoting it. But this is your decision.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume by doing `import com.fasterxml.jackson.*;` I am importing all?

No you do not, because a wildcard import is not recursive. You currently import every class in the package `com.fasterxml.jackson`, but since `ObjectMapper` is in the `databind` sub-package (i.e. `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`) it isn't included right now.

So either add:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
```

or do it more properly and import only the required class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

If you're using an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse then let it help you to import the required classes. Check the corresponding manuals to learn how to do that.